# htaccess redirect non existent path to a script

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a problem with one htaccess rule, i need that if someone call an non existent url with a specific syntax like:

```
http://www.somesite.com/somefolder/somefolder/123456978/unexistant_folder_nor_file_2015
```

where  **http://www.somesite.com/somefolder/somefolder/** exist and
**123456978/unexistant_folder_nor_file_2015** does not exist

the URL called will be passed to a script with below syntax:

```
http://www.somesite.com/somefolder/somefolder/index.php?id=/12345678/unexistant_folder_nor_file_2015
```

(where somefolder is always a folder with same name like, as example, test)

i tried below code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^somefolder/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /somefolder/somefolder/index.php?id=$1 [L, NC]
```

but doesn't work can someone give me some advice to solve this problem?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule inside **`/somefolder/somefolder/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /somefolder/somefolder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\d+/.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, this solve my first problem, but now I've a side effect.. all relative path are wrong :( as example src="image/test.jpg" became src="somefolder/image/test.jpg" there is a way to solve also this problem?

Comment: That is due to use of relative paths. To fix, you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: thank you very much! you solve all my problems :D thank you